# Override generated checkbox-name (via asp-for)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to change the name of a view-inputfield that is generated by an "asp-for" tag. This works when I add a "name=newname" with input fields of type 'text' or 'number'. But not when the inputfield is of type 'checkbox'. Then the "name=newname" is ignored. Any ideas why this is and how to solve it when using asp-for? I'm using AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0-rc2-final.

```
<input type="number" asp-for="@item.StatementSeqNr" name="StatementSeqNr" class="form-control" /> produces correct name:
<input name="StatementSeqNr" class="form-control" type="number" data-val="true" id="item_StatementSeqNr" value="5" />

<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.StatementActive" name="StatementActive" /> produces incorrect name:
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="item_StatementActive" name="item.StatementActive" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

Comment: The only way I found is to use some data attribute and overwrite the generated value in Javascript: <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@item.StatementActive" data-name="StatementActive" />

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible with the new TagHelpers.
You can achieve this by using the HtmlHelpers instead of the TagHelpers. They are still fully supported in asp.net core:

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => item.StatementActive, null, "StatementActive")
```